# Can Ubuntu run on a Mac with PowerPC?

Tags: system-installation, mac, powerpc, cpu-architecture

I have an iMac with a PowerPC chip in it. Can Ubuntu run on it? I have Mac OS X 10.4.11 running on it right now. The brand is Apple.

Comment: Have you looked at this and the pages it references? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run Ubuntu on your PowerPC Mac; you just need to get the PowerPC version.

Some third-party software is not provided for PowerPC and thus won't work, and since the PPC architecture is community-supported and has a relatively small installed user base these days, you may experience a few more bugs. But I say go for it--especially since [Mac OS X v10.4 Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Tiger) is *completely unsupported* and [no longer receives updates even for newly discovered security vulnerabilities](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2486899/mac-os-x/apple-signals-end-to-os-x-snow-leopard-support.html).

See these resources for more information:

- [PowerPCFAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ)
- [PowerPCDownloads](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads)
- [Which version of Ubuntu will work on my PowerPC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402225/which-version-of-ubuntu-will-work-on-my-powerpc)
  (which is a bit more specific than this question, and also hasn't been updated in a while)

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is particularly lightweight, so especially if this is an older PPC Mac (G3 or G3), [you might consider using that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu#PowerPC_systems). [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) is also lighter-weight than "vanilla" Ubuntu and has a ([much](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/01/dust-off-ibook-ubuntu-mate-powerpc-support-coming) [reported](http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/Ubuntu-MATE-Is-One-of-the-Last-Major-Distros-to-Officially-Support-PowerPC-474775.shtml) [on](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-MATE-14-04-1-LTS-to-Get-Official-PowerPC-Support-Dust-Your-Old-Mac-467813.shtml)) [PPC version](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-trusty-powerpc/).